# Python graphics

Tags: python, graphics, traceback

python is showing that there is an error although I have installed all the software necessary
Code:

```py
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 from graphics import *
win = GraphWin()
NameError: name 'GraphWin' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the necessary packages and in the right environment?

Comment: pip list | grep graphics

Answer (score 1):

You have to indicate in which folder you have installed Python. This has to be the same folder to install the graphics module. Otherwise, it is not discoverable by Python. You should be able to configure your folder for Python (either in IDLE, Spyder or PyCharm).